# Setting font markers to left-justified in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I have to design a symbology in QGIS following a very strict rulebook. I need to place certain attributes as at exact positions aroud the symbol. Since it is defined as part of the symbol, I do not us labels in this occasion but use font markers in addition to other symbols to create the symbol I need.

However, the text is of varying length. I can define offset and anchor point position but the text is always centred, which means longer text can cover the symbol etc. Is there a way to set the text of the font marker itself to left-justified?

Edit: I am trying to create symbols for certain emergency managment situations. Here is a rather complex example from the rulebook I have to follow for that. I am trying to add text similar to the text fields on the lower right corner of that example:
[image]

I suppose I can use rule based labels for this, but the style is meant to work in QGIS as well as in QField and a Geoserverapplication that we are supposed to use. In my experience labels tend to get messed quicker than symbols - but I may be mistaken hiere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be to use a constant number of characters and to apply the same offset everywhere. To achieve this, the `rpad()` function can be used to add spaces to the right of the current text.

It is not perfect though, as different letters have different width.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This works good enough, but requires some trial and error.